# Can two knights pieces attack one another from current positions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess

I am working on my Python skills and would like some feedback on this problem I have tried to solve. I would like to return a boolean if two knights at their current position can attack each other using standard chess notation example (4,'A')

```
from itertools import product

class ChessPosition:
    def __init__(self, number, letter):
        self.x = number
        self.y = letter
        self.notation_file_value = {
            "A": 1,
            "B": 2,
            "C": 3,
            "D": 4,
            "E": 5,
            "F": 6,
            "G": 7,
            "H": 8,
        }

    def get(self):
        return self.x, self.notation_file_value.get(self.y)


# get all possible knight moves from current position


def knight_moves(position):
    x, y = position
    moves = list(product([x - 1, x + 1], [y - 2, y + 2])) + list(
        product([x - 2, x + 2], [y - 1, y + 1]))
    moves = [(x, y) for x, y in moves if x >= 1 and y >= 1 and x < 8 and y < 8]
    return moves


# validate if knights can attack each other from current position
# if chess_position_1 can attack chess_position_2 
# then chess_position_2 can attack chess_position_1


def can_attack(chess_position_1, chess_position_2):
    k_1 = chess_position_1.get()
    k_2 = chess_position_2.get()

    for move in knight_moves(k_1):
        if move == k_2:
            return True
    return False

# True
print(can_attack(ChessPosition(2, "C"), ChessPosition(4, "D")))

# False
print(can_attack(ChessPosition(6, "A"), ChessPosition(5, "B")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of a stretch to apply OOP here, but fine. Keeping it, you should type-hint your `number` and `letter` arguments. Consider re-phrasing your `notation_file_value` as a subtraction of two character ordinals.

Your algorithm can be greatly simplified. Don't generate all moves - instead, just subtract the destination and source being checked, and if they're either (2, 1) or (1, 2) in an absolute sense, that's a valid knight move. Also, it's better named a move than an attack, since this logic will apply to non-attack moves.

Convert your prints to simple unit tests.

### Suggested

```
class ChessPosition:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int) -> None:
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    @classmethod
    def from_grid(cls, row: int, column: str) -> 'ChessPosition':
        return cls(row - 1, ord(column) - ord('A'))

    def __sub__(self, other: 'ChessPosition') -> tuple[int, int]:
        return self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y


def knight_can_reach(source: ChessPosition, dest: ChessPosition) -> bool:
    dx, dy = dest - source
    return sorted((abs(dx), abs(dy))) == [1, 2]


def test() -> None:
    assert knight_can_reach(ChessPosition.from_grid(2, 'C'), ChessPosition.from_grid(4, 'D'))
    assert not knight_can_reach(ChessPosition.from_grid(6, 'A'), ChessPosition.from_grid(5, 'B'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: How would from_grid handle a negative value passed for row?

Comment: @ShawnSheehan It does no validation of the position, so it will silently accept it. If you want to validate the position, you could do so within `__init__`.

Comment: FYI, the "file" in `notation_file_value` refers to the *files* (columns) of a chessboard, not to a filesystem entry.

Comment: yes @jwodder that's what I was going for but I can see how the name could be confusing.